# "Python Games" prompt has disappeared from menu

Tags: python, games

I am what I would call an old hand with computers but totally new to the Raspberry Pi. I am using it to try to learn Python and for this purpose I have copied out a program from "Raspberry Pi for Dummies"

I have saved the game in the folder home/pi - this may or may not be relevant!

Now for some unknown reason the "Python Games" prompt has disappeared from the "Main Menu". Under "Games" I just get "Minecraft Pi".

For the avoidance of doubt, the folder "python_games" remains intact and I can run them by "double clicking" the appropriate PY file or by opening the code in "Thonny" and selecting "F5".

The machine is a Pi3 using LXPanel 0.9.3

Comment: If you want all that stuff you have to download the heavy version of Raspbian from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ the regular version doesn't have that bloated stuff that most folks don't need. Direct download link is: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_full_latest

Comment: I already have it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly check if the 'Python Games' entry 'Show' checkbox has become unchecked:

Select Application Menu, Preferences, Main Menu Editor.

[image: unchecked]

Select the 'Games' entry on the left, if the 'Show' checkbox is unchecked, click the 'Show' checkbox and then click OK on the editor window.

If the 'Python Games' entry is missing:

[image: missing]

Click the 'New Item' button

[image: new item]

Enter the following:

- Name: Python Games
- Command: sh -c $HOME/python_games/launcher.sh
- Comment: Examples of games written in Python

[image: populated]

Click OK, Click OK on Editor window (DO NOT PRESS CANCEL or CLOSE WINDOW as I believe there is a bug that will lose changes)

To set the icon:

Right click on Application Menu,Games,Python Games. Select Properties. Click on icon.

[image: menu item properties]

Scroll down and select 'Python', click OK, click OK on Properties window.

[image]

Done

Comment: That's brilliant - I had the 2nd type of problem.All is good and running again perfectly now. All I need now is to know exactly why it worked and why it failed in the first place!

Comment: Great - please mark the answer.

Comment: No problem - I hope that I've maked it correctly!